# SDL2 texture cleared if I go to windows lock screen and come back or resize window

Tags: python, textures, sdl

I am using Python 3.6.5 with PySDL2 v.0.9.6. I am writing a program that has to draw thousands of little rectangles to the screen. I will never have to alter a given rectangle in any way once it is drawn to the screen, so I am just drawing them to a master texture and then drawing the texture to the screen on each loop iteration. This way, I don't have to redraw the thousands of rectangles every time I clear the screen -- I just have to redraw this one master texture that has all the rectangles.

The issue is that if I run the program for a while, go to the windows lock screen, log back in with my password and look at my program again, everything that had been drawn to the master texture that was there before is now gone. All the rectangles that were previously there have disappeared. The program is still running and drawing new rectangles though. I don't think it's just the windows lock screen -- sometimes if I let the program run while I do something in other applications, the same thing will have happened when I come back. I also noticed if I enable window resizing that resizing the window causes this to happen too.

Here is the relevant snippet from my code:

```
threading.Timer(0, request_data).start()
while running:
    ...

    sdl2.SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, screen_texture)
    while len(block_queue) > 0:
        sdl2.SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, block_queue[0][1], block_queue[0][2], block_queue[0][3], 255)
        sdl2.SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, block_queue[0][0])
        del block_queue[0]

    sdl2.SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, None)
    sdl2.SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255)
    sdl2.SDL_RenderClear(renderer)
    sdl2.SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, screen_texture, None, screen_texture_rect)
    sdl2.SDL_RenderPresent(renderer)
```

The "request_data()" function is just a function that runs in a separate thread and adds new rectangles to the queue to be drawn.

I know this is a general SDL issue and not a PySDL2 issue because I have the exact same issue in another program I'm writing in C++ SDL2.

Comment: This behaviour is known as "device loss" in directx world, and SDL uses directx on windows by default. You can use e.g. opengl which doesn't have device loss (at a cost), or you can react to `SDL_RENDER_TARGETS_RESET` event and recreate your render textures (static textures are recreated by SDL itself).

Comment: @keltar how do I tell SDL to use OpenGL instead of DirectX in my code?

Comment: Something like `sdl2.SDL_SetHint(sdl2.SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl")` between `SDL_Init` and window creation (I don't really use python for that so it is more of a guess-based conversion from C).

Comment: @keltar that fixed it, thank you!!